# Reset Index in Python

Tags: python, pandas

The ask is simple from a DataFrame of ~3400 I have selected a specific column:

```
df1 = df.loc[df["date"] == "2019-12-19 09:31:00+05:30"]
```

output:

```
       date                       open   high    low    close   volume
16  2019-12-19 09:31:00+05:30   32171.5 32171.5 32138.8 32149.0 39420
```

Now what I need is

```
a = 32171.5
```

For this I have tried

```
a = df1.at[16,'high']
```

With this I get the desired result but what I want is to be able to call the value with index 0 so that I can make the code more dynamic as today it is appearing on index 16 later it could be index 4.

Also I cannot use any other info like Date,Open,or any other column as they are all dynamic so column names are the only option I have.

Comment: Add a `tolist()` at the end

Comment: So instead of some random indexes, you need indexes to be from 0 to K, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `df1` only have one row, you could simple get the first (only) row and get the cell value:

```
a = df1.iloc[0]['high']
```

Comment: I love this one single code

Comment: OK, closed, be free correct this

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is in your question title, you can use:

```
df1.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

To reset the index to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Change the indexes from 0 to len(df).
    import numpy as np

```
df1 = df.loc[df["date"] == "2019-12-19 09:31:00+05:30"]
df1.index = np.arange(0,len(df1))
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
      date                       open   high    low    close   volume
0  2019-12-19 09:31:00+05:30   32171.5 32171.5 32138.8 32149.0 39420
```